# I can read that there *are* chars in a file, but not print them out to another file

Tags: c, printf

So if I say `fprintf(output, "hello");` it prints hello a bunch of times so it definitely recognizes there are characters inside. But the file is blank when I say to print c.

How do I get it to print the chars from one file into another?

edit: those declarations above are for the rest of the code but I'm just trying to test the printing for now.

edit: still solving this. Might just use redirection from putty.

Answer (score 0):

To output a character, use the `%c` format specifier:

```
fprintf(output, "%c", c);
```

or you can use `fputc()` for this job.

Comment: Okay I have this: 'fprintf(output, "c%", c);' but it's only printing "cccc" so why is it not printing what is contained?

Comment: @HelloKomputer: It's `%c`, not `c%`.

Comment: Okay so my input file allcrazy, has code like this: some/* crazy */stuf in it an when I tried to read from allcrazy and print to output it just gives me a very long underline squiggly red error line and says to // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="comment">

I don't care if it gives a syntax error but it's not printing anything at all.

Comment: It's hard to tell what error you are talking about. But if there's a syntax error, isn't that what you should solve first?

Comment: well the output is a c source file, so if it's not code there's going to be an error regardless. I just did it for a .txt file and there is still just a ton of space that you can highlight but no visible text.

Comment: @HelloKomputer Use a minimal code with `fgetc` and `fprintf` or `fputc` to test, remove the other stuff first, if it works for the minimal code, the error must be somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how your compiler implements `getc` but I suspect the line

```
   int getc(allcrazy);
```

has something to do with the crazy behavior you are seeing.

With minor changes, your code works just fine. This is what I have that works like a charm.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) 
{
   FILE *allcrazy;
   FILE *output;

   allcrazy = fopen("allcrazy.c", "r");
   output = fopen("output.c", "w");

   int c, readChar;
   // STATE state = READING_INPUT;
   int errorLine = 0;
   // int getc(allcrazy);


   while (c = fgetc(allcrazy) != EOF) {
       fputc(c, output);
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your primary problem is the insufficient parentheses in this line:

```
while (c = fgetc(allcrazy) != EOF) {
```

It assigns 0 or 1 to `c`, and tries to write <kbd>Control-A</kbd> characters to the output file.  The code is equivalent to:

```
while (c = (fgetc(allcrazy) != EOF)) {
```

You need to use:

```
while ((c = fgetc(allcrazy)) != EOF) {
```

This does the assignment before the comparison.  Since `c` is an `int`, you should be in with a decent chance from here…well, as long as you fix the printing too.

The `printf()` statement in the body of the loop is also flawed; you don't include a format string.  You should use `putc(c, output);` or `fprintf(output, "%c", c);` — or you can use `fputc(c, output);` though I really don't see a need for that here.

As written (`fprintf(output, c)`), you pass an `int` where the function expects a character pointer.  Your compiler should be complaining about this.  If it isn't, you need to turn up the warning levels until it does, or you need to get a better compiler.  And you need to heed warnings from your compiler; remember, at this stage, it knows a lot more about C than you do.